# Unsubscribe from email notifications about job messages

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

I recieved job message and email. How do I unsubscribe from this email?

There is no convenient "unsubscribe" link at the bottom of email:

---

[image]

---

In the "email preferences" I have everything `OFF` and empty job alerts.

Comment: Have you also made sure that your job search status is "Not interested in jobs"? That setting also says that it effects how many emails they send.

Comment: @BSMP, I have "Actively looking right now" set. Where it says anything about emails?

Comment: Under the option for "Actively looking right now" it says, *"Maximum matches. We'll get you in front of employers ASAP **and send you any new jobs that match your interests**."*. That's probably why you're still getting emails.

Comment: @BSMP, there is "Inbox" on the "Jobs - Messages" page, "send" should mean only send to there. Not emails. I don't want emails.